# Bash syntax, square brackets and -d option

Tags: bash, npm

I have this command in bash:

```
[ -d node_modules/phantomjs ] || npm install -g phantomjs
```

I am not sure what it means in plain English...

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/test

Comment: I researched google before posting. Why -1??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means :

If "node_modules/phantomjs" is not directory, run "npm install -g phantomjs"

See [wikipedia true/false](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_and_false_%28Unix%29)